# Aligning two mboxes side by side

Tags: vertical-alignment

I come across this quite a lot and usually end up trying different things until it's barely acceptable but I really don't understand what is going on.

This:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.35]
        \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (R) at (0,-1.7);
        \coordinate (S) at (1.7,-1.7);
        \coordinate (T) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (U) at (0.4,1.7);
  \coordinate (V) at (-1.7,1.7);
  \coordinate (Q) at (-1.7,0);
  \draw[<->]  (Q)node[ left ]{Q} -- (T)node[ right ]{T} ;
  \draw[<->]  (R)node[below]{R} -- (P)node[below left=1em and 1em]{P} -- (U)node[right]{U};
  \draw[<->]  (V)node[left]{B} -- (S)node[right]{S} ;
  \draw (-0.4em,-0.4em) rectangle (0,0);
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](V,P,Q);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](R,P,S);
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](S,P,T);
  \tkzMarkSegment[size=0.4,pos=0.5,mark=|](V,S);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\hfill
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{ 0.46\textwidth}\

    I would like to have this box start at the top of the one to the left

\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

This ends up looking like this

[image]

Comment: Why don't use two mini pages side-by-side?

Comment: I tried to wrap it in a minipage and got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach #1: Using one TikZ picture for everything

I do use an additional package, `tikzpagenodes` to facilitate positioning and the TikZ library `fit` to create a node surrounding the graph, but everything can go into one `tikzpicture` environment.

> [image: ![enter image description here]

To effectively using the page nodes, you need to call `remember picture` so that TikZ remembers the positions of those nodes and the nodes defined relative to them.

Though the image doesn't show it, I've left `showframe` in the keys for `geometry` so you can see how things align with respect to the page margins.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.35,baseline=(current bounding box.north),remember picture]

  \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (R) at (0,-1.7);
  \coordinate (S) at (1.7,-1.7);
  \coordinate (T) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (U) at (0.4,1.7);
  \coordinate (V) at (-1.7,1.7);
  \coordinate (Q) at (-1.7,0);

  \draw[<->]  (Q)node[ left ]{Q} -- (T)node[ right ]{T} ;
  \draw[<->]  (R)node[below]{R} -- (P)node[below left=1em and 1em]{P} -- (U)node[right]{U};
  \draw[<->]  (V)node[left]{B} -- (S)node[right]{S} ;
  \draw (-0.4em,-0.4em) rectangle (0,0);

  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](V,P,Q);
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](R,P,S);
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](S,P,T);
  \tkzMarkSegment[size=0.4,pos=0.5,mark=|](V,S);

  \node[draw,
        fit=(current bounding box.north west) 
            (current bounding box.south east),
       ] (LEFT) {};

  \node[anchor=north east,
        text width=0.46\textwidth,
        draw,
        ] 
    (B) at (LEFT.north east-|current page text area.east)
    {I would like to have this box start at the top of the one to the left};

\end{tikzpicture}%%

\end{document}
```

## Approach #2: Using you TikZ picture and minipage

Getting the TikZ picture to properly line up with the minipage turned out to me more of a hassle than I'd imaged it would be.  So, instead of trying to get the two environments to agree about where the *top* of each was relative to each other (I could get it very close, but not exact), I decided to use `\raisebox`.  And, voila!  It works perfectly.  And there's no need for additional packages.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\raisebox{-\dimexpr\height}
         [0pt]
         [\dimexpr\height+\depth]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (0,-1.7);
    \coordinate (S) at (1.7,-1.7);
    \coordinate (T) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (U) at (0.4,1.7);
    \coordinate (V) at (-1.7,1.7);
    \coordinate (Q) at (-1.7,0);

    \draw[<->]  (Q)node[ left ]{Q} -- (T)node[ right ]{T} ;
    \draw[<->]  (R)node[below]{R} -- (P)node[below left=1em and 1em]{P} -- (U)node[right]{U};
    \draw[<->]  (V)node[left]{B} -- (S)node[right]{S} ;
    \draw (-0.4em,-0.4em) rectangle (0,0);

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](V,P,Q);
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](R,P,S);
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](S,P,T);
    \tkzMarkSegment[size=0.4,pos=0.5,mark=|](V,S);


    \draw (current bounding box.north east)  rectangle (current bounding box.south west);

  \end{tikzpicture}}%%
\hfill
\raisebox{-\height}
         [0pt]
         [\dimexpr\height+\depth]
  {\fbox{%%
    \begin{minipage}{ 0.46\textwidth}
      I would like to have this box start at the top of the one to the left
    \end{minipage}}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\adjustbox` and align both boxes at their very top.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign=T}{\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.35]
  \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (R) at (0,-1.7);
  \coordinate (S) at (1.7,-1.7);
        \coordinate (T) at (3,0);
  \coordinate (U) at (0.4,1.7);
  \coordinate (V) at (-1.7,1.7);
  \coordinate (Q) at (-1.7,0);
  \draw[<->]  (Q)node[ left ]{Q} -- (T)node[ right ]{T} ;
  \draw[<->]  (R)node[below]{R} -- (P)node[below left=1em and 1em]{P} -- (U)node[right]{U};
  \draw[<->]  (V)node[left]{B} -- (S)node[right]{S} ;
  \draw (-0.4em,-0.4em) rectangle (0,0);
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](V,P,Q);
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](R,P,S);
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.4,mark=|](S,P,T);
  \tkzMarkSegment[size=0.4,pos=0.5,mark=|](V,S);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=T}{\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
    I would like to have this box start at the top of the one to the left
\end{minipage}%
}}

\end{document}
```

Beware of the missing `%` or you get unwanted spaces.

[image]